# Image is cropped in ImageView android

Tags: android, imageview

I have set an image with src tag in ImageView. The problem is in some device(my Moto E2), the image is shown properly but in devices(my Xiaomi Redmi 1s), the image is cropped with black background. I don't understand why this is happening. I have also tried setting the scaleType as centerInside but it doesn't help. I am attaching the screenshot and code also for reference.

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="140dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/web_hi_res_512" />
```

Redmi 1S Image
[image: Redmi 1S]

Moto E2 Image

[image: Moto E2]

Comment: I think scaleType fit center should do it.
PS: Black background is due to android version difference. I think you have elevation setsomewhere

Comment: It doesn't help. Tried that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set following attribute to your ImageView:

```
            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"/>
```

Comment: I tried that. It doesn't help. I forgot to mention it in question.

Comment: did you try, setting the image as background, not as src?

Comment: I even don't understand the redmi image is blurry but moto one is not.

Comment: did setting the drawable as background solve the cropping? Blurry might be, due to different resolutions of your drawable.

Comment: set the background in imageview?

Comment: set The background to @android:color/transparent. This should remove background.

Comment: What does the original drawable look like? is it a png, a 9patch, a layered drawable?

Comment: Now I got it. After setting as background. One image also overlaps it because i have set image through code also. Fixed it. Thanks fr the help.